# ExtendedRequestsLibrary from robot framework has depreciation to_json error

Tags: python, api, robotframework

I just downloaded the ExtendedRequestsLibrary, and I cannot seem to even import it. The code crashes before any code execution when I import using

`Library        ExtendedRequestsLibrary`

I am getting the errors:

```
[ ERROR ] Unexpected error: AttributeError: 'to_json' is deprecated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/utils/application.py", line 83, in _execute
    rc = self.main(arguments, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/run.py", line 443, in main
    result = suite.run(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/model.py", line 259, in run
    self.visit(runner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/model/testsuite.py", line 174, in visit
    visitor.visit_suite(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/model/visitor.py", line 85, in visit_suite
    if self.start_suite(suite) is not False:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/runner.py", line 74, in start_suite
    ns.handle_imports()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/namespace.py", line 55, in handle_imports
    self._handle_imports(self._imports)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/namespace.py", line 66, in _handle_imports
    self._import(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/namespace.py", line 74, in _import
    action(import_setting)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/namespace.py", line 128, in _import_library
    import_setting.alias, self.variables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/importer.py", line 48, in import_library
    lib = self._import_library(name, positional, named, lib)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/importer.py", line 78, in _import_library
    lib.create_handlers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/testlibraries.py", line 111, in create_handlers
    self._create_handlers(self.get_instance())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/testlibraries.py", line 243, in _create_handlers
    method = self._try_to_get_handler_method(libcode, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/testlibraries.py", line 271, in _try_to_get_handler_method
    return self._get_handler_method(libcode, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/testlibraries.py", line 350, in _get_handler_method
    return getattr(libinst, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ExtendedRequestsLibrary/__init__.py", line 111, in __getattribute__
    raise AttributeError("'%s' is deprecated." % name)
```

I tried both on Mac and Windows, and I am getting the same issue, and cannot seem to find anything online.

Thank you!

Comment: The library looks outdated, and supporting py2 only - you are running it on 3.7. The last released version is from Mar 31, 2016 - I'd suggest you switch from it to something maintained - like the RequestsLibrary.

Comment: Aaah I see that makes sense, thank you! Will checkout alternatives.

Comment: Had the same issue and solved it by downgrading robotframework from 3.2.1 to 3.1.2 with ```pip install robotframework==3.1.2```